# How to resolve excel error 2029 with #NAME?

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I read an excel file and on a cell I got a text like this:

`"=- Bla Bla Bla".` 
This will not be recognize and will show `#NAME?`

So if you need to read some cell and get it into database this error in the file will show as `Error 2029`. The script will freeze.
So, can I pre-replace the content if I get `=` or `-` chars in the cell so I validate the content before I read it and get the error. Can I pass over it!

I need cell validation

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    c = Target.Cells.Column
    r = Target.Cells.Row
    'validate cell
End If
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that the cell cannot have any `=` or `-`? Or are those two characters just not allowed at the *start* of a cell's value?

Comment: Yes, but some ppl get them into it and save useless/crappy information's ! I need a way not to let them do that!

Comment: Was the "yes" for the 1st or 2nd question? If you don't want the characters at the very start, then try the 1st data validation formula I gave in my answer. If you don't want the characters at all, then try the 2nd. If either one helps you, then you can upvote it even if you don't accept it as your answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

```
'verify cell for data
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    c = Target.Cells.Column
    r = Target.Cells.Row

    If IsError(Target.Worksheet.Cells(r, c)) Then
        MsgBox "You have a validation Error!"
        Target.Worksheet.Cells(r, c) = ""
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sTemp As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Check if cell has error
        If IsError(.Range("A1").Value) Then
            '~~> Check if it is a 2029 error
            If .Range("A1").Value = CVErr(2029) Then
                '~~> Get the cell contents
                sTemp = Trim(.Range("A1").Formula)
                '~~> Remove =/-
                Do While Left(sTemp, 1) = "=" Or Left(sTemp, 1) = "-"
                    sTemp = Trim(Mid(sTemp, 2))
                Loop
                '~~> Either put it in back in the cell or do
                '~~> what ever you want with sTemp
                .Range("A1").Formula = sTemp
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add Data Validation to your worksheet to prevent things from being entered that way. Under "Validation criteria", allow "Custom" and enter this formula:

```
=NOT(OR(IF(EXACT(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),"-"),1,0),IF(EXACT(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),"="),1,0)))
```

If the value entered in the cell begins with a "-" or "=" (with leading spaces), then it won't accept it. If the person typed in `=123`, then it would be valid since it's treated like a formula and will only see it as `123`.

If you don't want the cell to contain `=` or `-` *at all*, then try this for your data validation formula. Again, it won't be able to catch a formula like `=NOW()` or `=-hi` (it would see `#NAME?` for `-hi`), but it will reject `=-123` since it sees `-123`. If you have the cells formatted as **Text**, then it will reject any cell with `=` or `-` inside because values starting with `=` aren't treated like formulas.

```
=NOT(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("=",A18)),ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A18))))
```

Comment: I need cell validation problematically!

Comment: I've updated my answer, as well, with a couple different methods depending on what you need exactly.